# MapView loads in Android API 19, gray in newer versions

Tags: android, google-maps

I have an Android app that suddenly stopped displaying map tiles in production a few days ago. Instead, the map shows a gray screen with the Google logo as if the key was invalid. We haven't recently deployed the app or changed the keys.

I created a new key and rebuilt the app in Android studio. After a few tweaks, the map loads correctly in a `MapView` on Android 19.

However, in the simulator and a real device, the map is still gray in later versions (eg 26, 27).

If I instead replace the app's MainActivity with the sample `MapFragment` from the [Maps docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/start), the map loads and is interactive on all platforms. If I then switch back to the `MapView` and rebuild the app, the map will display any tiles that were loaded by the `MapFragment` -- but nothing additional gets loaded when panning and zooming. There are no obvious logcat errors.

I've upgraded to the latest play services (`'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0'`, `'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'`), updated gradle, invalidated caches and restarted, wiped and reinstalled simulator devices -- consistent behavior.

[image: left screenshot shows Android API 27 without a map; right shows Android API 19 with map loading correctly]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular instance, the problem appears to have been caused by the interaction of Google Maps services and the `EventBus` library. Updating both to the latest version resolved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Seems issue is in life cycle events handling. From ['MapVew' description](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView):

> Users of this class must forward all the life cycle methods from the
>   `Activity` or `Fragment` containing this view to the corresponding ones in
>   this class. In particular, you must forward on the following methods:
>
> ```
> onCreate(Bundle)
> onStart()
> onResume()
> onPause()
> onStop()
> onDestroy()
> onSaveInstanceState()
> onLowMemory()
> ```
>
> A GoogleMap must be acquired using `getMapAsync(OnMapReadyCallback)`.
>   The `MapView` automatically initializes the maps system and the view.

You must call `mMapView.onCreate(bundle)`, `mMapView.onStart()` etc. inside each corresponding method of `Activity` or `Fragment` with `MapView` layout.

Comment: Hmm, I've got all those lifecycle methods, and the map does load fine on earlier versions of Android -- but not later.

Comment: @MattHampel May be real time [location permissions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/location)? Actually its hard to help you without any source code...